# Leaflet: Capturing points for features inside circle

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, circle

I'm using the leaflet draw tool to create a circle and then finding the points inside the circle. My data is from GeoJSON, and the code works as far as figuring out how many points are inside, but I want to then capture the point in a new array, test.push.layer doesn't work, it seems to create a null object, not a layer.

```
if (type == 'circle') {
    var test = [];

    var theCenterPt = layer.getLatLng();
    var theRadius = layer.getRadius();
    var counter_points_in_circle = 0;

    // Loop through each point in GeoJSON file  //var allPoints = L.geoJson(data); 
    allPoints.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        var theLayer = layer;
        // Lat, long of current point
        layer_lat_long = layer.getLatLng();
        // Distance from our circle marker To current point in meters
        distance_from_centerPoint = layer_lat_long.distanceTo(theCenterPt);
        // See if meters is within radius
        if (distance_from_centerPoint <= theRadius) {
            counter_points_in_circle += 1;

            test.push.layer;     //Fails

        }

    });
    alert(counter_points_in_circle);  //Works.
    alert(test.features.length);    //test.features is undefined..
    alert("results "+JSON.stringify(test));  //results [] 
    alert("results "+JSON.stringify(test.toGeoJSON()));  //test.toGeoJSON is not a function
}
```

Comment: It might be a scope issue.  I commented your code here, since it isn't an answer but troubleshooting:  https://gist.github.com/roma0104/b50d62ad6fdb7440f8c2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what finally worked..

test.push(layer.feature);

Then I could see my results in

```
alert(test.length);   
alert("results "+JSON.stringify(test));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `test` variable is declared as an array. You should use:

`test.push(layer)`

`test.length`

`L.layerGroup(test).toGeoJSON()`